# Prior to JUnit 4, which methods do you override to prepare for the test run, and clean up after the test run?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

Is it:

`init()` and `after()`

`setUp()` and `tearDown()`

`before()` and `after()`

`init()` and `tearDown()`

`setUp()` and `after()`

`before()` and `tearDown()`

Comment: setUp() and tearDown()

Comment: Sounds like a homework question, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JUnit follows a very specific sequence of events when invoking tests. First, it constructs a new instance of the test case for each test method. Thus, if you have five test methods, JUnit constructs five instances of your test case. After constructing all of the test case objects, JUnit follows these steps for each test method:

- Calls the test case's `setUp()` method
- Calls the test method
- Calls the test case's `tearDown()` method

In the `setUp()` Method you can open a network connection for example (`prepare`)
In the `tearDown()` Method you can close a network connection for example (`clean up`).
This process can be used for easy prepare and clean up a test case.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean "prepare/cleanup the test *case*" (i.e. test method), it's `setUp` and `tearDown`. Both are declared in `junit.framework.TestCase`.